# Python Code meaning: str.split(line[:-1],',')

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have this piece of code:

```
f = open('scores.txt','r')
L = []
for line in f:
    L = L + map(float,str.split(line[:-1],','))
print(L)
```

Can you please explain the meaning of the following command and its parameters as I'm completely new to Python:
    str.split(line[:-1],',')

Comment: Removing the last character in the line (prolly the new line character) and then splitting on `,`. Would have been better written as `line[:-1].split(',')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your file `scores.txt`, which contains a lot of numbers. These numbers are separated by commas.
You go through the file (line by line) and put all of those numbers into one big list.

Each line ends with the newline-symbol. That's why you cut away the last symbol with `line[:-1]`.

The numbers are separated by commas, so you take this line and cut/split it at each comma with `line[:-1].split(',')`.

When reading from a file, you read everything as text. To allow further computation, you tell Python to regard it as number, more precisely as floats/ rational numbers.

By the way, I think map does not work like this in Python 3. But an equivalent code is:

```
f = open('scores.txt','r')
L = []
for line in f:
  L = L + [float(s) for s in line[:-1].split(',')]    
print(L)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty bad (Python 2.x) code idiom for reading a file whose lines are comma-separated lists of floats:

1. It iterates over the file by reading each `line` and manually stripping newline character(s):

   - Bad: `line[:-1]` is a bad way of stripping the trailing newline: it breaks on Windows which has \r\n
   - Better: in Python 3, `open()` defaults to `newline=None`, which enables universal newline support, and correctly handles \r, \n or \r\n . Or you can explicitly set `open(..., newline=??)`. Then just use `line` as is, no need for the hacky `line[:-1]`
2. `str.split(line[:-1], ',')` splits a line of comma-separated strings of floats into a list of strings of floats. Except it's equivalent to `line[:-1].split(',')`. But now thanks to the newline support we can do `line.split(',')` which is just heaps clearer.
3. `L = [] for line in f:
   L = L + map(float, str.split(line[:-1],','))` is an old 2.x way of appending to a list-of-lists. Also we can use a list comprehension instead of `map(float, ...)`. And we can use a nested list-comprehension to eliminate the `for line in f:` loop.
   So:

   `f = open('scores.txt','r')
   L = [ [ float(flt) for flt in line.split(',') ] for line in f ]`

or even better, we use a context-handler to automatically handle open'ing, close'ing f and related exceptions. So the code reduces to:

```
with open('scores.txt','r') as f:
    L = [ [ float(x) for line in f x in line.split(',') ]
```